# Swift: Cannot convert the expression's type '$T3' to type '$T4'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsdate

What I am trying to achieve is convert a birthdate string in this format: `08/15/2014` to an `NSDate` instance. And then converting the `NSDate` back to a `String` but in `ISO format`.

Why am I receiving this error message?
**Cannot convert the expression's type '$T3' to type '$T4'**

```
// birthdateString = 08/15/2014
let birthdateString = KeychainManager.getString(KeychainManager.StaticVars.kFbBirthdate)

let birthdateAsNSDate = Date.parseFacebookBirthdate(birthdateString)
let birthdateAsISOString = Date.getStringFromDate(birthdateAsNSDate)
```

**Date Conversion Class**

```
class Date {

class func parseFacebookBirthdate(birthdateString: String) -> NSDate {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(birthdateString)
}

class func getStringFromDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}

}
```

I am getting the error on this line:

```
let birthdateAsNSDate = Date.parseFacebookBirthdate(birthdateString)
```

Comment: I cannot compile your Date class because the result of `dateFormatter.dateFromString(birthdateString)` needs to be unwrapped. – What type does `KeychainManager.getString()` return? Does the problem also happen with a fixed string `let birthdateString = "08/15/2014"`?

Comment: @MartinR I actually solved this, I had to unwrap `birthdateString` and `birthdateAsNSDate`. That's all that was required. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I just had to unwrap `birthdateString` and `birthdateAsNSDate` when calling my `Date` functions.

Pretty simple fix =]

```
let birthdateString = KeychainManager.getString(KeychainManager.StaticVars.kFbBirthdate)
let birthdateAsNSDate = Date.parseFacebookBirthdate(birthdateString!)
let birthdateAsISOString = Date.getStringFromDate(birthdateAsNSDate!)
```